# Как сделать split в Arduino?

Tags: python, c#, arduino

У меня есть дата (тип переменной - строка) - 03.04.2022 и мне нужно сделать так что-бы в условной переменной "date" было значение "03", а в переменной "mounth" значение "04", а в переменной "year" значение 2022. Как я могу это реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
t = '03.04.2022'
a = t.split('.')
print("date ", a[0])
print("mounth", a[1])
print("year ", a[2])
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Стой. А разве это не python?

Comment: python, чистый как слеза